# How to I create an event for user entry?

Tags: python, events, input, menu, tkinter

As part of my program I am asking the user for their name and their class (high school class). I am using a text entry function which is successfully accepting the input but I need help on validation: I only want the 'Enter' button to become active once the user has actually started typing as otherwise the user will press the 'Enter' button and deactivate it. Also, I would like to make sure that when they enter their name the program will only accept letters and no numbers at all. For the second entry (school class/tutor class) the user will enter something like 6A1 which is their class. There are about 10 different senior classes in my school so how can I either validate the entry to accept only 1 of these 10 classes or perhaps a drop down menu? Help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
class Enter_Name_Window(tk.Toplevel):
    '''A simple instruction window'''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Label(self, width=40, height=2, text= "Please enter your name and class." )
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        enter_name = Entry(self)
        enter_name.pack()
        enter_name.focus_set()


        def callback():
            self.display_name = tk.Label(self, width=40, height=2, text = "Now please enter your tutor group.")
            self.display_name.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
            tutor = Entry(self)
            tutor.pack()
            tutor.focus_set()
            Enter_0.config(state="disabled")

            Enter_0_2 = Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=self.destroy)
            Enter_0_2.pack()


        Enter_0 = Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=callback)
        Enter_0.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to do what you literally asked, "the 'Enter' button to become active once the user has actually started typing" is to bind the change or keypress event on the `enter_name`, and activate `Enter_0` once it's triggered.

But that's probably not what you actually want. If the user enters some text and then deletes it, wouldn't it be nicer if the button disabled again? And if the user pastes some text without typing anything, shouldn't that enable the button?

To do that, you want one of two things: validation, or variable tracing.

---

Before we get into it, you're almost certainly going to want to store the `Enter_0` button as an attribute on `self` instead of creating and re-creating new buttons on top of each other. So, I'll do that in my example.

---

Validation, although it's very badly documented in Tkinter and a bit clumsy to use, is very powerful, and the obvious fit for what you're trying to do—validate text:

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    # existing stuff

    vcmd = self.root.register(self.validate)
    enter_name = Entry(self, validate='key', validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'))

    # existing stuff

    self.Enter_0 = Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=callback)
    self.Enter_0.pack()

def validate(self, P):
    self.Enter_0.config(state=(NORMAL if P else DISABLED))
    return True
```

This probably looks like unreadable magic, and the Tkinter docs give you no guidance. But the Tk docs for [`validatecommand`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/entry.htm#M16) show what it means:

- The `key` bit means that the command "will be called when the entry is edited".
- The `%P` means the "value of the entry if the edit is allowed". You can stick as many of those `%` strings as you want into your `vcmd`, and they will be passed as arguments to your `validate` method. So, you could pass `(vcmd, '%s', '%P', '%v')` and then define `validate(self, s, P, v)`.
- You can do anything you want in the function, and then return `True` or `False` to accept or reject the change (or return `None` to stop calling your validation function).

Anyway, now, if the user attempts to edit the entry in any way, then the `Enter_0` button will be set to `NORMAL` if their edit would give you a non-empty string, `DISABLED` otherwise.

---

Variable tracing is conceptually a lot clunkier, but in practice often simpler. It's also not completely documented, but at least it's *somewhat* documented.

The idea is to create a [`StringVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), attach it to the `Entry`, and put a "write trace" on it, which is a function that gets called every time the variable is updated (which happens every time the `Entry` changes contents). Like this:

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    # existing stuff

    name_var = StringVar()
    def validate_enter():
        self.Enter_0.config(state=(NORMAL if var.get() else DISABLED))
    name_var.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode: validate_enter)
    enter_name = Entry(self, textvariable=name_var)

    # existing stuff--and again, do the self.Enter_0 change
```

Comment: I am getting an error from vcmd = self.root.register(self.validate)?

Comment: I am confused as to why enter_name = Entry has been defined twice?

Comment: @user3056786 Presumably you don't have a `self.root` anywhere, and I assumed you did. You probably want `self.parent`, or a global `root` or similar. (By the way, in the future, don't just say "I am getting an error", post the actual error and traceback so people can read exactly what went wrong instead of having to guess.)

Comment: @user3056786: Meanwhile, I showed two different options for solving your problem, each of them defines `enter_name` exactly once. If you want to do _both_ options (which there's probably no good reason to do), you can, but you have to merge both sets of changes into your original code, not copy and paste both (in other words, define `enter_name` once, passing both the `validate` args and the `textvariable` arg).

Comment: @user3056786: I've created a stripped-down, cleaned-up version of your code, and put complete working versions of each alternative [here](http://pastebin.com/gWssTgPp) and [here](http://pastebin.com/XZkxkLcW) to show you the idea better.

Comment: @user3056786: Also see [Tkinter Validation](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/12/tkinter-validation.html) for a lot more information.

Comment: @user3056786: What is "the event"? What is not working, and how is it not working?

Comment: I want to make sure the 'Enter' button is only ACTIVE when the user is typing - so if the entry box is empty then the button should be disabled

Comment: @user3056786: OK, are you running one of my two examples? If so, which one? And on which platform, Python version, Tk version, etc.? Because they both work for me everywhere I test them. If you're running _different_ code, what _are_ you running? I can't debug your code if I can't see it.

Comment: @user3056786: Also, I'm still not sure I understand your explanation, because "when the user is typing" and "the entry box is empty" are not exclusive. When the user first starts typing, they're both true. After he's finished typing, they're both false. Which rule do you want—"when the user is typing, enable the button" or "when the box is empty, disable the button"? (My examples do the second of those.)