# Text entry event?

Tags: python, user-interface, events, tkinter, tkinter-entry

As part of my program I ask the user for their name and class (high school class). Once the user presses 'Enter' after typing their name the button is disabled and the 'tutor' field appears. However, the user is in essence able to submit their name even if they haven't typed anything. I only want the 'Enter' button to be active once the user has started typing.

What I have done below doesn't seem to work :(

Also, my input validation doesn't work - know why?

```
class Enter_Name_Window(tk.Toplevel):
    '''A simple instruction window'''
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Label(self, width=40, height=2, text= "Please enter your name and class." )
        self.text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        name_var = StringVar()
        def validate_enter_0():
            self.Enter_0.config(state=(NORMAL if name_var.get() else DISABLED))
            print("validate enter worked")

        name_var.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode: validate_enter_0)
        enter_name = Entry(self, textvariable=name_var)
        enter_name.pack()
        enter_name.focus_set()


        def callback():
            if len(name_var) > 10 or any(l not in string.ascii_letters for l in name_var):
                print("Input validation worked")

            self.display_name = tk.Label(self, width=40, height=2, text = "Now please enter your tutor group.")
            self.display_name.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


            tutor_var = StringVar()
            def validate_enter_2():
                self.Enter_0_2.config(state=(NORMAL if tutor_var.get() else DISABLED))
                print("validate enter worked")
            tutor_var.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode: validate_enter_0_2)
            tutor = Entry(self, textvariable=tutor_var)
            tutor.pack()
            tutor.focus_set()

            self.Enter_0.config(state="disabled")

            self.Enter_0_2 = Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=self.destroy)
            self.Enter_0_2.pack()


        self.Enter_0 = Button(self, text="Enter", width=10, command=callback)
        self.Enter_0.pack()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687124/python-tkinter-disable-the-button-until-all-the-fields-are-filled

Comment: Is this meant as a followup to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20622044/how-to-i-create-an-event-for-user-entry/20622282#comment31391807_20622282), or an entirely new question which is in some way different? (And, if the latter, in what way is it different?)

Comment: Also, as I told you on the previous question, please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)—something we can actually run and debug—instead of just a random fragment of code.

Comment: And as a side note, it's really bad style to (as your code must be doing) `from Tkinter import *` and `import Tkinter as tk` and `import Tkinter`. Just do one of those, not all of them, and use the names consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first obvious problem is this line:

```
tutor_var.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode: validate_enter_0_2)
```

You've created a function that takes three variables, and returns the `validate_enter_0_2` function as a function object. That doesn't do any good.

You want to create a function that *calls* the `validate_enter_0_2` function. Like this:

```
tutor_var.trace('w', lambda name, index, mode: validate_enter_0_2())
```

You have the exact same problem with `name_var` and will also need to fix it there, of course.

---

On top of that, you don't actually *have* a function named `validate_enter_0_2` to call, because you defined it as `validate_enter_2`. This means your validation function just raises a `NameError` instead of doing useful. Or, if you have a `validate_enter_2` function defined somewhere else in your code, it calls the wrong function. (This is one reason that cryptic names like `enter_0_2` and `enter_2` are not a good thing.)

---

There's at least one other problem with your code: You're repeatedly trying to use `name_var`, which is a `StringVar` object, as if it were a string. You can't do that. And if you actually look at the console output, Tkinter will tell you this, with tracebacks like this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "tkval2.py", line 25, in callback
    if len(name_var) > 10 or any(l not in string.ascii_letters for l in name_var):
AttributeError: StringVar instance has no attribute '__len__'
```

And that exception is happening before you get a chance to create the new `Entry`.

To fix that, you need to call `get` on the `StringVar` whenever you want to get its value, like this:

```
if len(name_var.get()) > 10 or any(l not in string.ascii_letters for l in name_var.get())
```

---

Finally, as I explained in the answer to your other question, your `trace` validator isn't going to get called until something changes. This means you will either need to call it explicitly, or explicitly `name_var.set('')`, or just start the button off disabled. As written, it will start off enabled, and only disable if you type something and then erase it.

---

I'm not sure whether those are the only problems with your code, but all of them will certainly prevent your validation from working as expected. So, you need to fix all of them, and any other errors in your code, before it will work.

---

From your comments:

> I am however wondering how to create a pop up message displaying an error…

When do you want to do that? What condition do you want to check, and when do you want to check it?

At any rate, as in most GUIs, the way to "pop up" anything like this is a dialog. [Dialog Windows](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) in the Tkinter book explains everything you need to know. But you don't need to copy-paste all that code, or write it from scratch; the stdlib comes with [Tkinter helper modules](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules) that do most of the work for you. In your case, you probably just want [`tkMessageBox`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_messagebox.htm).

> … and something that forces the user to re enter their name

Force them how? Just erasing the existing Entry contents would leave them with an empty box to fill in, which would also disable the button. Is that what you want?

Anyway, guessing at what you want, it could look something like this:

```
def callback():
    if len(name_var.get()) > 10:
        tkMessageBox.showerror("Bad name", "Your name is too long. What's wrong with good American names like Joe?")
        name_var.set('')
        return
    # the rest of your code here
```

In the `callback` function (called when they click the button after typing their name), instead of just checking some condition and printing something out, I check a condition and pop up an error dialog, clear out the existing name, and return early instead of creating the second half of the form. I didn't handle your other condition (any non-ASCII letters), but it should be obvious how to add that.

However, validation like this might be better done through actual validation—instead of making them wait until they click the button, catch it as soon as they try to type the 11th character, or a space or accented character, or whatever else you don't like. Then you can pop up a message box, and either disable the button until they fix it, reject/undo the change (which is easier with a `validatecommand` function than with a `trace` function, as shown in my answer to your previous question).

One last thing: Instead of a message box, it may be better to just embed the error as, say, a Label that appears in the form itself (maybe with the error description in red, with a big flag icon). This is common in web apps and in more modern GUIs because it provides more immediate feedback, and is less obtrusive to the user flow.

Comment: Thanks a lot the validation and event handler are both working. I am however wondering how to create a pop up message displaying an error and something that forces the user to re enter their name. Thanks

Comment: @user3056786: Those are somewhat vague questions. They also seem like followups that should be one or more separate questions here. But I'll edit the answer to try to get you started.